# Product of marginals absolutely continuous with respect to a Borel probability measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $\Bbb{R}^{m+n}=\Bbb{R}^m\times\Bbb{R}^n$. Consider its marginal measures $\mu_1(A):=\mu(A\times\Bbb{R}^n)\, (A\in\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R}^m))$ and $\mu_2(B):=\mu(\Bbb{R}^m\times B)\, (B\in\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R}^n))$.

**Question)** What are some necessary/sufficient conditions (or special cases) on $\mu$ for the absolute continuity $\mu_1\otimes\mu_2\ll\mu$ to hold? I am interested in investigating measures $\mu$ for which $\mu_1\otimes\mu_2$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$.

Some special cases that I have explored:

1. Suppose $\mu$ is a discrete probability measure supported in the finite subset $S\subset\Bbb{R}^{m+n}$. Then $\mu_1\otimes\mu_2\ll\mu$ iff $\pi_1(S)\times\pi_2(S)=S$ where $\pi_1:\Bbb{R}^m\times\Bbb{R}^n\rightarrow\Bbb{R}^m$ and $\pi_2:\Bbb{R}^m\times\Bbb{R}^n\rightarrow\Bbb{R}^n$ are projection maps.
2. Suppose $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure  on $\Bbb{R}^{m+n}$ with the density function $f=f(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2)$ where $(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2)\in\Bbb{R}^m\times\Bbb{R}^n$. Then the density function for $\mu_1\otimes\mu_2$ is $f_1(\mathbf{x}_1)f_2(\mathbf{x}_2)$ where
   $f_1(\mathbf{x}_1):=\int f(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2){\rm{d}}\mathbf{x}_2$ and $f_2(\mathbf{x}_2):=\int f(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2){\rm{d}}\mathbf{x}_1$. (All these functions are non-negative and Borel measurable.) Denote the zero locus $f=0$ by $Z$. The absolute continuity $\mu_1\otimes\mu_2\ll\mu$ amounts to $(\mu_1\otimes\mu_2)(Z)=0$, i.e. $f_1(\mathbf{x}_1)f_2(\mathbf{x}_2)=0$ for a.e. $(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2)\in Z$. Next, notice that $f_1(\mathbf{x}_1)f_2(\mathbf{x}_2)=0$ means either $f_1(\mathbf{x}_1)=0\Leftrightarrow \lambda\big((\{\mathbf{x}_1\}\times\Bbb{R}^n)\setminus Z\big)=0$ or $f_2(\mathbf{x}_2)=0\Leftrightarrow \lambda\big((\Bbb{R}^m\times\{\mathbf{x}_2\})\setminus Z\big)=0\,$
   ($\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}^m$ or $\Bbb{R}^n$).
   In conclusion, $\mu_1\otimes\mu_2\ll\mu$ iff for Lebesgue a.e. $(\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2)\in Z$ either
   $(\{\mathbf{x}_1\}\times\Bbb{R}^n)\setminus Z$ or
   $(\Bbb{R}^m\times\{\mathbf{x}_2\})\setminus Z$ is
   of Lebesgue measure zero. Thus by taking $Z$ to be the complement of a product set, we arrive at a family of examples: Let $A\subseteq\Bbb{R}^m$ and  $B\subseteq\Bbb{R}^n$ be of positive Lebesgue measures and let $f:\Bbb{R}^{m+n}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ be a Borel function with $\int f=1$ which is moreover positive on $A\times B$ and zero elsewhere. Then for the Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $\Bbb{R}^{m+n}$ whose density is $f$ one has $\mu_1\otimes\mu_2\ll\mu$.
3. A family of non-examples: Suppose $\mu$ is supported in a compact subset $C$ of $\Bbb{R}^m\times\Bbb{R}^n$. If $C$ does not decompose into a product; that is $C\neq\pi_1(C)\times\pi_2(C)$, then $\mu_1\otimes\mu_2$ is not absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$. Because then one can choose open subsets $U_1\subset\Bbb{R}^m$ and $U_2\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ such that $(U_1\times U_2)\cap C=\emptyset$—hence $\mu(C)=0$—but both open subsets $U_1\times \Bbb{R}^n$ and $\Bbb{R}^m\times U_2$ intersect $C$ non-trivially, hence along subsets of positive measure. In particular: $(\mu_1\otimes\mu_2)(U_1\times U_2)>0$.

**Remark)** The following MSE posts discuss the absolute continuity in the reverse direction, i.e. $\mu\ll\mu_1\otimes\mu_2$.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3901510/joint-measure-and-absolute-continuity-wrt-product-of-marginals
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054873/marginally-continuous-measures